# How to make a checkpoint commandblock but make it only go once

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a map and I have a command block to detect when the player is on a gold block and a chain command block to say the message in chat but it spams it until I get off the gold block, Is it possible to make so it'll only say it once? (The repeating command block command is: `execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-0.35~ gold_block run spawnpoint @s ~ ~ ~ -90`)
[image] [image]

Comment: I assume it spams because the command gets repeated? There also seems to be a discrepancy between the title and the body of your post: can you edit either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the repeating command block to `Needs Redstone` you can prepare it with a Redstone block next to it, you can then add another chain command block that is also set to `Contitional` and use `setblock` to replace the Redstone block with air.